# Laravel - Struggling to insert data that has been changed by javascript into the database

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to insert data into my database but I cannot seem to get this date of birth form to be accepted. Here's a jsfiddle of what my form is 
https://jsfiddle.net/10990b6t/2/ however when I try send this data into my database it just returns me to the register page. I previously had a plain textbox and it worked fine but obviously doesn't have the javascript making the form a lot better.

--Old textbox that worked--

```
<label for="title">Date of Birth</label>
<input type="text" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth">
</div>
```

--New attempt at form that doesn't work-- registerForm.blade.php

```
    <input
    type="text"
    name="date"
    id="dateofbirth"
    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
    onkeyup="
        var v = this.value;
        if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        } else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        }"
    maxlength="10"
>
```

AuthController.php

```
 function registerUser(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'firstname' => 'required|min:3|max:25',
            'surname' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'postcode' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|min:5|max:30|unique:users',
            'password' =>'required|min:5|max:30|',
            'dateofbirth' => 'required',
        ]);
        //create a User object
        $user = new User();
        $user->firstname = $request->firstname;
        $user->surname = $request->surname;
        $user->address = $request->address;
        $user->postcode = $request->postcode;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = $request->password;
        $user->dateofbirth = $request->dateofbirth;
        $user->role = 1;

        $user->save();
        return redirect('all');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expecting a field named `dateofbirth` and your input has name="date" it should be name="dateofbirth"

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="dateofbirth"
    id="dateofbirth"
    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
    onkeyup="
        var v = this.value;
        if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        } else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        }"
    maxlength="10"
>
```

Comment: No problem :p consider accepting my answer when you'll be able to :)